# How to store the list of data into session with single line in codeigniter

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

I want to store the list of data into session with single line and then how to extract that data on view.userData variable contains list of data.I can store the data like below that i know.but instead of writing multiple line can i store with single line.and how can i extract that data to use on view.Thanks in Advance.

```
          $userData=$google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
          $this->session->set_userdata('userdata',$userData['id']);
          $this->session->set_userdata('username',$userData['given_name'];
```

### Can I store the data like below?

```
      $this->session->set_userdata('userdata',$userData);
```

### How can use the variable on view like this it is giving nothing

```
 <?php if(!empty($userdata['given_name'])){?>
    <li><a href="#">HI &nbsp;<?php echo $userdata['given_name'];?></a></li>
  <?php }
```

Comment: Are these code snippets on the same php page?

Comment: No view is different file.and remaining in single file.

Comment: print_r($_SESSION); in the view page and see if the username is the session variable.

Comment: $this->session->set_userdata('username',$userData['given_name']; when i use this variable on view it is working.What i want to store all the data with single mentioned above  and how extract on view.

Comment: How are you passing $userData to the view? Are you using something like $data['userdata'] = $userData; before passing $data to the view ?

Comment: It want to store all the data into session and then  use it.

Comment: Have you read the user_guide? In particular... https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data and https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the Codeigniter User Guide on sessions, where this is explained ( as we all have ), you could do the following...

This is demonstration code which is really good for testing stuff out like this.

**The View** auth_view.php for want of a better name

```
<h1> View </h1>
<?php if(!empty($this->session->given_name)){?>
    <li><a href="#">Hi <?= $this->session->given_name;?></a></li>
<?php }
```

**The Controller**

```
// $userData=$google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
// Recreate the Array from google_oauthV2
$userData['id'] = 1;
$userData['given_name'] = 'Fred Flintstone';

$this->session->set_userdata($userData); // Save ALL the data from the array
var_dump($this->session->userdata()); // DEBUG-  Lets look at what we get!

$data = $this->load->view('auth_view', NULL, true);
echo $data;
```

Does that help explain the possibilities?

**I highly recommend reading the user guide, because I did to get this answer.**

Answer (score 0):

This is hard for me to answer as I don't know how the set_userdata() function works, ie will it accept an array.

But you could try:

```
$userData=$google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
$this->session->set_userdata('data',$userData);
```

And on the view page:

```
<?php if(!empty($data['userData']['given_name'])){?>
<li><a href="#">HI &nbsp;<?php echo $data['userData']['given_name'];?></a></li>
```

If that does not work this is what I would do.

```
$userData=$google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
$this->session->set_userdata('userdata',$userData['id']);
$this->session->set_userdata('username',$userData['given_name']);
$_SESSION['data'] = $userData;
```

And on the view page:

```
<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['data']['userData']['given_name'])){?>
<li><a href="#">HI &nbsp;<?php echo $_SESSION['data']['userData']['given_name'];?> </a></li>
<?php }
```

Also you are missing a right paren on:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('username',$userData['given_name'];
```

in your orginal code.

Comment: Yikes... this is one of my pet peeves...  $data[userdata]['given_name'] for what reason would you not have quotes around userdata when you have around 'given_name'.... Both should be quoted else PHP will initially think userdata is a constant... Someone should turn on their error_reporting :)

Comment: @TimBrownlaw That was not intentional, I fixed it, thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: @itsme Ive updated my code because of small typos... I think I got them all out.  Also make sure you take care of that typo for the right paren in your set user data function.

Comment: what i don't understand is  you are storing data to variable $_SESSION['data'] = $userData;                                   
why are u again using userData here  ($_SESSION['data']['userData']['given_name'])

Comment: @itsme  I really apologize for this, I made a tone of typos I just found another that would have made a difference.  Try the first method again.

Comment: Yes, the $_SESSION can hold the data you want from page to page. We make a field in the session variable to hold the userData like so. $_SESSION['data']. And access it like $_SESSION['data']['userData']['your userData field']

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167921/discussion-between-joseph-j-and-itsme).

Comment: I got the solution how would i expected.can you check above solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store data like this:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('userdata',$userData);
```

To access it from view, just store the session data into a local variable.

```
$userData = $_SESSION['userdata'];
```

then you can use it.

```
  <?php if(!empty($userData['given_name'])){ ?>
    <li><a href="#">HI &nbsp;<?php echo $userData['given_name'];?> </a></li>
 <?php } ?>
```

**NOTE:** 
     To use session in codeigniter you have to load the session library in your controllers.You can load it in constroctor or top of the method where you are going set session.(you don't have to load it to view.)

```
$this->load->library('session');
```